# Expression contains mixed types: DecimalField, IntegerField. You must set output_field

Tags: django, orm

I am trying execute a query with multiple annotates and i keep getting the output_field required error where as i am already writing that.

I have tried to change the output to decimal but does not work.
Any idea?

My targeted code

```
    count = ShareAllocation.objects.filter(session_key=self.storage.request.session.session_key). \
        values('share_type__id', 'share_type__code', 'share_type__type'). \
        annotate(share_count=Sum('share_type__id')). \
        annotate(total_shares=Sum('number_of_shares')). \
        annotate(total_paid=ExpressionWrapper(F('amount_paid') * F('total_shares'), output_field=models.IntegerField)).\
        annotate(total_unpaid=ExpressionWrapper(
                                F('amount_unpaid') * F('total_shares'), output_field=models.IntegerField
                               )
                 ).\
        count()

    if count == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working for me. You might be missing the parens after the field type.

```
class PCSTradeManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PCSTradeManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(
            income = ExpressionWrapper(F('count_contracts') * F('credit') * Value(00), output_field=DecimalField())
        )
```